# How to interactively read in two inputs and use them in a function call

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am currently taking a class to learn elisp so I have no experience with this language. I am trying to interactively read in two inputs (the width and length of a rectangle) and then use them to call a function to compute the area of the rectangle. The code I have is as follows:

```
(defun rectangle_Area(w l)
"Compute the area of a rectangle, given its width and length  interactively."
(interactive "nWidth: ")
(interactive "nLength: ")
(setq area (rectangleArea w l))      
(message "The rectangle's area is %f." area))
```

Currently I get a wrong number of arguments error. 
Like I said, I have no previous experience... all I really need to know is how to store/read in two separate values using interactive.

Thank you for any help

Comment: I'm rather curious about who is offering a class in elisp?

Comment: Protip, avoid function names that are so similar (differ only by `_`).  Also, elisp naming convention is to use `hyphen-separated-words`.  Have fun!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `interactive` <kbd>RET</kbd>:

> To get several arguments, concatenate  the individual strings,
>   separating them by newline characters.

So we have:

```
(defun rectangle_Area(w l)
    "Compute the area of a rectangle, given its width and length  interactively."
    (interactive "nWidth: \nnLength: ")
    (setq area (rectangleArea w l))      
    (message "The rectangle's area is %f." area))
```

Comment: I tried that previously and it did not work but I think it was because I had an extra character. It did work, thank you very much!!